# Why lag1, may be 2 or 3, of the PACF plot seem to be more significant than a higher lag?

Tags: lags, partial-correlation

I am attempting to interpret the PACF plot generated from the daily return of the market index.

As it can be seen on the graph, AR(1) seems to be the most appropriate model since the partial autocorrelation is significant at lag 1. However, according to a lot of examples shown in the internet, I found that most of the example of the PACF plot interpretation mainly concentrates on the lag1, or may be 2 or 3, regardless of the significant lag at higher lag. For instance, even though that the partial correlation is significant at 23, 30 and 31, with a lag length of 31, but if the lag 1 is significant then it is going to be AR(1). Or if lag 1 is insignificant, then the series is generated on a random manner. So, [ 1] I would like to ask that why we mainly rely on lag1

[2]According to my PACF plot, How should I make a comment on the lag 23,30 and 31. Since, for instance, the return at t and t-31 are compared at lag 31 and it is significant, so does it mean it is possible to predict the return on a monthly basis?

[image]

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Al4Zyp7bfeKdxkez0UG-Q-kTgKIM: Series of return data, excel

Many thank

Thomas

Comment: The acf .and pacf is useful to identify models under certain conditions. Perhaps these conditions don't hold for your data. Please post your data and I will try and help,

Comment: @IrishStat, the question does not require data, and an answer based on a particular dataset might not answer the general question. I suggest leaving the data alone and explaining the conceptual issue. ThOmAs, you might want to check out earlier posts by searching the right keywords here on Cross Validated; I suspect a similar question might have been asked and answered before.

Comment: The general question often needs to be answered in the the specific as ":the devil is in the details".'

Answer (score 1):

ARIMA modelling can be a very powerful tool BUT like all model specifications there are assumptions. An ARIMA model is not a panacea.  Good econometricians are taught early to test "model specification assumptions" . A critical assumption is that if you have daily data then you must not omit any observations. You data has missing values(dates eg. 4.21.12 where the financial markets were closed.) My observation/finding could only be found by examining the time series in question.

Other assumptions of ARIMA modelling is that there needs to be a constant variance in the (to be found) error process . Also there needs to be no pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses ( like a monday effect) or local time trends. You data clearly has "spikes' which need to be explained either via dummies or known events.

Often times in daily data there are deterministic effects like day-of-the-week , month-of-the-year and even week-of-the-month or day-of-the-month. These need to be factored into the equation culminatimg in a Transfer Function with possible ARIMA structure.

An example of a daily model can be found here http://autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation starting at slide 48

When an OP asks a very general question like this one it is insufficient to deliver a "Sermon from the Mount" like read the book ! but rather to provide possible specific help regarding logic flaws in their approach. Actual assumption testing much like an earlier Thomas can often be very useful.

Comment: This does not appear to be a "very general question," because it specifically asks about this PACF plot.  Is there anything constructive you could say about it?

Comment: the acf and pacf can get confused when you have missing observations as is in this case. For example if there is a monthly effect and you skip observations this can lead to the kind of acf that the OP presented. Also the acf and the pacf can get confused when you have either changes in model parameters or changes in error variance over time.. much like regression coefficients ( which they are ! ) .

Comment: Thank you!  I find those comments instructive and appreciate that they are grounded in long experience.